# Cakephp elements and for each loops

Tags: cakephp

I'm breaking my head some time now on the following cakePHP code:

This is my controller:

```
<?php
class HeaderController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

     public function index() {

    }

    public function usp() {
       return $this->set('usp', $this->Header->query('SELECT * FROM USP WHERE Actief = 1'));
    }

}
```

And this is my element:

```
            <? 
                $UNSP = $this->requestAction('header/usp');
                print_r($UNSP);
foreach($UNSP['header'] as $USPs): 
    echo $USPs['USP']['Naam']; 
endforeach;
```

The query works and is executed when the page loads. I get an errormessage saying Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/View/Elements/header.ctp, line 9]

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: My guess is your use of `$UNSP['header']` should be `$UNSP['Header']`. What does the contents of `print_r($UNSP)` actually look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming, somehow, that `$UNSP` in the view will be populated with the view variable you set in the `usp()` action. This is not how `requestAction()` works. `requestAction()` can either echo out the view that you call, or return the value of the *function* you're calling.

Instead, since it seems that `usp()` doesn't have a view but instead is just used to get data, you should return it like so

```
public function usp() {
   return $this->Header->query('SELECT * FROM USP WHERE Actief = 1');
}
```

Then, in your view, tell `requestAction()` that you want the results of the function call:

```
$UNSP = $this->requestAction('header/usp', array('return'));
```

Now `$UNSP` should contain the results of the query.

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks (Got some other errors now but will figure that out myself)